# exe4j high dpi settings

Tags: java, exe, highdpi, exe4j

What are the best settings for creating an executable to run on windows 10 with scaling.

I have tried setting the DPI-aware on true and false, but nothing seems to have effect. I've also tried several system-properties but without any succes either. I currently have following settings in my exe4j.xml

```
dpiAware="false"
amd64="false
```

I'm still running JDK 8, but since the application is being run in the entire company, I can not immediately upgrade to another version of the java runtime ( although i would like to ;) )

And override the High-DPI settings using the windows-properties. But I don't like that solutions.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't make a software implement High-DPI support correctly by specifying some (magic?) flag.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 does not have High-DPI support for Windows, you have to upgrade to Java 11+.

Comment: I just run into the issue that the titlebar is not scaling when using exe4j with Java 17. When building without exe4j the titlebar scales properly. Any idea what causes this issue?